# Prove that $E((X-a)^2)$ is minimized when $a=E(X)$

Tags: probability

$X$ is an arbitrary continuous random variable.

I tried to do this by saying since $X-a$ is squared that means its lowest possible value is 0 and then I tried to solve for $a$ when the expression is $0$.

$$
\begin{align}
E((X-a)^2)&=0\\
E(X^2)-2aE(X) +a^2&=0\\
a^2-2aE(X)+E(X)^2&=E(X)^2-E(X^2)\\
(a-E(X))^2&=E(X)^2-E(X^2)\\
a-E(X)&=\sqrt{(E(X))^2-E(X^2)}\\
a&=E(X) \pm\sqrt{(E(X))^2-E(X^2)}\\
\end{align}
$$

Now I don't know if there's some trick to say that $\sqrt{(E(X))^2-E(X^2)}=0$ or if I'm barking up the wrong tree with this approach.

Comment: Just consider $E((X-a)^2$ as a quadratic polynomial on $a$, using the linearity of expectation. The value doesn't have to be $0$ in general.

Comment: @shrimpabcdefg I assume you're leading me to taking derivatives to find the minimum the "regular" way but I'm not well-versed on derivatives and expected values so that's why I tried to side step that approach.

Comment: You don't need derivatives to minimize quadratic polynomials. Just use the "complete-the-square" method

Comment: @EwanDelanoy, I did complete the square to solve for $a$ when I assume the expression equals 0 so I think there's a trick or rule that I'm not aware of or is slipping my mind that you're treating as obvious.

Comment: Let us put it this way : what is the minimum of $(a-7)^2$ when $a$ is a real variable ? Of $(a-11)^2$ ? Etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By linearity of expectation, we have

$E((X-a)^2)=a^2-2E(X)a+E(X^2)=(a-E(X))^2+E(X^2)-E(X)^2$. Considering this as a quadratic function on $a$, it is clear that the minimum is acquired when $a=E(X)$.

Comment: Your final answer is my 4th line, so I'm sorry it isn't clear to me why that is the case.

Comment: Thank you. Should not the expectation be like in the discrete case: $$
E\left[ \left( X-\mu \right) ^2 \right] \sum_x{\left( X-\mu \right) ^2p\left( \left( X-\mu \right) ^2 \right)}
$$

Answer (score 5):

For every $a\in\mathbb R$ we have:$$\begin{aligned}\mathsf{E}\left(X-a\right)^{2} & =\mathsf{E}\left(X-\mathsf{E}X+\mathsf{E}X-a\right)^{2}\\
 & =\mathsf{E}\left[\left(X-\mathsf{E}X\right)^{2}+2\left(X-\mathsf{E}X\right)\left(\mathsf{E}X-a\right)+\left(\mathsf{E}X-a\right)^{2}\right]\\
 & =\mathsf{E}\left(X-\mathsf{E}X\right)^{2}+\mathsf{E}2\left(X-\mathsf{E}X\right)\left(\mathsf{E}X-a\right)+\left(\mathsf{E}X-a\right)^{2}\\
 & =\mathsf{E}\left(X-\mathsf{E}X\right)^{2}+2\left(\mathsf{E}X-a\right)\mathsf{E}\left(X-\mathsf{E}X\right)+\left(\mathsf{E}X-a\right)^{2}\\
 & =\mathsf{E}\left(X-\mathsf{E}X\right)^{2}+2\left(\mathsf{E}X-a\right)\left(\mathsf{E}X-\mathsf{E}X\right)+\left(\mathsf{E}X-a\right)^{2}\\
 & =\mathsf{E}\left(X-\mathsf{E}X\right)^{2}+\left(\mathsf{E}X-a\right)^{2}\\
 & \geq\mathsf{E}\left(X-\mathsf{E}X\right)^{2}
\end{aligned}
$$

LHS takes minimum value iff $a=\mathsf EX$

Comment: Thank you very much. Should not the expectation be like in the discrete case: $$
E\left[ \left( X-\mu \right) ^2 \right] \sum_x{\left( X-\mu \right) ^2p\left( \left( X-\mu \right) ^2 \right)}
$$

Comment: @Avv Sorry, but the expression you provide in your comment is "unreadable" for me. Secondly the generality of the answer makes any distinction between "discrete" and "not discrete" irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to say that why we don't substitute $x$ in $E(x) = \sum x p(x)$ with $(X-\mu)^2$ please and then work out it that way?

Answer (score 3):

Let's define a function which depends on $ a $:

$$ f \left( a \right) = \mathbb{E} \left[ \left( X - a \right)^{2} \right] $$

Now, the optimization problem is:

$$ \hat{a} = \arg \min_{a} f \left( a \right) $$

The requirement for optimal point - $ f' \left( \hat{a} \right) = 0 $.
Working on the function as in the answer by @shrimpabcdefg:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{d a} f \left( a \right) & = \frac{d}{d a} \mathbb{E} \left[ \left( X - a \right)^{2} \right]  \\
& = \frac{d}{d a} {a}^{2} - 2 a \mathbb{E} \left[ X \right] + \mathbb{E} \left[ X \right]^{2} \\
& = 2 a - 2 \mathbb{E} \left[ X \right] \\
& \Rightarrow 2 \hat{a} - 2 \mathbb{E} \left[ X \right] = 0 \Rightarrow \hat{a} = \mathbb{E} \left[ X \right]
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 2):

Your error is in the very first line of your displayed equations where you assume that the minimum value that $E[(X-a)^2]$ is $0$ and attempt to solve for $a$.  The minimum value of $E[(X-a)^2]$ (regarded as a function of $a$) is *not* $0$; it is $\sigma^2$ where $\sigma$ is the standard deviation of $X$.  Keep in mind that $(E[X])^2 - E[X^2]$ is generally a negative number (it equals $-\sigma^2$) and so the value of $a$ that you compute as the minimizer of $E[(X-a)^2]$ is actually a complex number.